# Formalizing a result from vector algebra of motion of curve in a plane

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a curve $\gamma(t) = ( x(t), y(t) )$ in the plane. We know that the velocity is $v(t) = \gamma'(t) = (x'(t), y'(t) ) $ and if we write $(v_x, v_y)$ for the velocity components in each direction, then $v_x = x' $ and $v_y = y'$. We always use the fact that

$$ \dfrac{ d y }{d x } = \dfrac{ v_y }{ v_x } $$

and the proof my prof gives is this:

$$ \frac{ dy }{dx} = \dfrac{ dy/dt }{dx /dt } = \frac{ v_y }{v_x} $$

but this seem to me artificial. Can someone pintpoin a source where I can find this result and similar results proved rigorously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the scenario we have: we are given a differentiable curve $\gamma: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^2$, and we suppose that for every $t \in \Bbb{R}$, $\gamma_1'(t) \neq 0$. Now, fix a particular parameter value $t_0 \in \Bbb{R}$.

Now, since we assumed $\gamma_1'(t_0) \neq 0$, it follows that atleast in a neighbourhood of $t_0$, the function $\gamma_1 : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is invertible (this is the inverse function theorem). Now, let's calculate the quantity $(\gamma_2 \circ \gamma_1^{-1})'(\gamma_1(t_0))$. Well, this is straight-forward from the formula for differentiating an inverse function and chain rule:
\begin{align}
(\gamma_2 \circ \gamma_1^{-1})'(\gamma_1(t_0)) &= \gamma_2'\left[ \gamma_1^{-1}(\gamma_1(t_0))\right] \cdot (\gamma_1^{-1})'(\gamma_1(t_0)) \tag{chain rule} \\
&= \gamma_2'(t_0) \cdot \dfrac{1}{\gamma_1'(t_0)} \tag{derivative of inverse} \\
&= \dfrac{\gamma_2'(t_0)}{\gamma_1'(t_0)},
\end{align}
which is precisely what you wanted to prove.

---

Now, when reading this, you may be wondering how does any of this correspond to the formula
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}. \tag{$\ddot{\smile}$}
\end{align}

Well, to understand that, you need to understand precisely what is meant by $(\ddot{\smile})$. Note that on the LHS $y$ is supposed to be interpreted "as a function of $x$", where as on the RHS, $y$ and $x$ are "functions of $t$". So, what is going on here?

Well, let me now rephrase the entire argument above in a more common notation, but which slightly abuses notation. Note that when we have a parametrized curve $\gamma: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^2$, if we write it as $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$, then above when I said $\gamma_1'(t) \neq 0$, it means $x'(t) \neq 0$. This means we can invert the equation to express "$t$ as a function of $x$". So, we have a function $x \mapsto t(x)$. If we compose this with $t \mapsto y(t)$, we obtain the composite function
\begin{align}
x \mapsto y(t(x))
\end{align}
i.e this is what we mean by "expressing $y$ as a function of $x$" to make sense of the LHS of $(\ddot{\smile})$. Now, we have to calculate the derivative of this function. This is the chain rule again:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dx} y(t(x)) &= \dfrac{dy}{dt} \cdot \dfrac{dt}{dx} \\
&= \dfrac{dy}{dt} \cdot \dfrac{1}{dx/dt} \\
&= \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}
\end{align}

---

Once again, the crux of the argument is the chain rule and inverse-function theorem which tells you how to calculate the derivative of an inverse function. The way I wrote things in the first part of my answer makes very explicit what are the functions involved, where the derivatives are being evaluated etc. The second way is the more traditional way of writing things, which is definitely more sloppy with notation (maybe more understandable?). I suggest you compare the two presentations so that you can see how to "translate" between the two ways of writing, but as a summary,

1. "$x$ as a function of $t$" strictly speaking refers to the function $\gamma_1:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$.
2. "$y$ as a function of $t$" strictly speaking refers to the function $\gamma_2:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$.
3. "$y$ as a function of $x$" strictly speaking refers to the composite function $\gamma_2\circ \gamma_1^{-1}:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, and it is to this function that we apply the chain rule.

In any case, the reason the formula is true is not because you just "divide top and bottom by $dt$", if that's what you're worried about. But, having given this proof, it is of course much easier to remember the result if you think of it as "divide top and bottom by $dt$", and just keep this more detailed explanation in the back of your mind.