# How to understand the chain rule in derivatives for the functions in parametric form?

Tags: derivatives, parametric, chain-rule

Consider the following paragraph and equations [from the NCERT textbook regarding the derivatives of functions in parametric form](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/lemh105.pdf#page=33).

> Sometimes the relation between two variables is neither explicit nor
> implicit, but some link of a third variable with each of the two
> variables, separately, establishes a relation between the first two
> variables. In such a situation, we say that the relation between them
> is expressed via a third variable. The third variable is called the
> parameter. More precisely, a relation expressed between two variables
> x and y in the form $x = f (t), y = g (t)$ is said to be parametric form
> with t as a parameter.
>
> In order to find derivative of function in such form, we have by chain
> rule.
>
> $$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}.\dfrac{dx}{dt} $$
>
> $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}
>  \text{(whenever} \dfrac{dx}{dt} \ne 0)$$

I have doubt with the first equation of the chain rule $\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}.\dfrac{dx}{dt} $. As we can see that $y$ is not directly dependent on $x$, but only on $t$, then how can chain rule assumes  $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ in the equation?

Comment: Take a look at [Formalizing a result from vector algebra of motion of curve in a plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3624726/568204).

Answer (score 1):

Since $x$ and $y$ are both parameterised by $t$, they can't vary independently - they are coupled to each other. Which means that, given some value of $x$, there are only very specific values that $y$ can take.

In fact, as long as we are careful about things, we can say that since $x$ is a function of $t$, you can invert that so that $t$ is a function of $x$ - i.e. $x = f(t) \implies t = f^{-1}(x) = t_x(x)$. Then that means that $y$ can *also* be written as a function of $x$, ie. $y = g(t_x(x))$, and under a few simple assumptions you can say that differentiablity is preserved when you do so.